# Why has the use of "plague" in OED (sense 2a), as a verb declined?

Tags: word-choice

***Plague***, when used as a verb, meaning *To trouble, tease, bother, annoy, or pester, usually repeatedly, insistently, or constantly; to constitute a nuisance, threat, or danger to. Freq. in pass* (OED sense 2a), seems to me to have declined.

> 1595   Spenser Amoretti xli, in Amoretti & Epithalamion sig. C6,   If
>   her nature and her wil be so, That she will plague the man that loues
>   her most.
>
> 1616   B. Jonson Epicœne i. ii, in Wks. I. 534   It giues thee law of
>   plaguing him.
>
> 1637   J. Bastwick Letany i. 21,   I will..so plauge the
>   Metropolicallity of Yorke and Canterbury.
>
> 1658   W. Johnson tr. F. Würtz Surgeons Guid ii. xii. 94   Patients in
>   this case are commonly plagued with a cough.
>
> a1681   J. Lacy Sr. Hercules Buffoon (1684) iii. iii. 28,   I am so
>   plagued with Citizens, that I cannot have a Deer that's mans meat, but
>   they steal it out of my Park, my Lord.
>
> 1728   J. Gay Beggar's Opera i. viii. 9   Husbands and Wives..plaguing
>   one another.
>
> 1767   P. Gibbes Woman of Fashion II. 171   What a dickens would you
>   have more!.. I won't hear you, I won't be plagued.
>
> a1817   J. Austen Persuasion (1818) IV. x. 221,   I really cannot be
>   plaguing myself for ever with all the new poems and states of the
>   nation that come out.
>
> 1833   H. Martineau Tale of Tyne ii. 33   The big boys used to plague
>   him, and he plagued the little ones.
>
> 1893   Dict. National Biogr. at Margaret Tudor, Queen of Scotland,
>   In 1541 she was again plaguing Henry with her money troubles.
>
> 1952   J. L. Waten Alien Son 105   You and your questions!.. Do you
>   have to plague me, too?
>
> 1989   Chron. of Horse 1 Sept. 51/3   When the above measures are
>   followed, even horses that have been plagued by sore feet..will
>   usually show great improvement.

I do not include here the use of OED sense 1, which meaning is: 
*To afflict (a person, community, country, etc.) with a plague, or with a difficulty or misfortune as if with a plague; to visit calamity or misfortune on (a person, etc.), esp. as a punishment or expression of displeasure.*

When I was a child in the 1950s, in Norfolk, my parents generation made frequent use of it, often to describe the pesterings of their children - *he keeps plaguing me to buy him a twin-barrelled bazooka*. Nowadays I seldom, if ever, hear it used.

Is this the experience of others? And why might it be the case? It does seem to be an expressive conveyance, both of one's annoyance, as well as illustrative of the supplicant's intensity.

What might we use instead, which is more *in vogue*?

Comment: Are you sure your perceptions are representative? [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=plagued+him%2Ctroubled+him%2Cteased+him%2Cbothered+him%2Cannoyed+him%2Cpestered+him&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplagued%20him%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctroubled%20him%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cteased%20him%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbothered%20him%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cannoyed%20him%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpestered%20him%3B%2Cc0) might be said to indicate they're not.

Comment: "Is this the experience of others?" - Not mine.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Google Ngrams only report the written instances, not everyday speech. We must take WS2's word when he states that he doesn't *hear* people use the verb plague as often as before. As for "why", maybe schools don't teach about the plague as much as they used to. Maybe "plague" has lost its derogatory tone over the years, and has been replaced by "bugging" and "nagging"—who knows!

Comment: @Mari-Lou A I hope you will admit that it's pretty clear I haven't challenged WS2's honesty about his perceptions, merely a lack of research (though not worthy of the downvote someone has plagued him with) directed at finding general data himself. I wonder if you've looked at the contrasting Ngrams,  which I chose in an attempt to investigate possible shifts in preferences?  FWIW, I've noticed a decline in the use of 'plagued', less so perhaps when followed with 'by flies'. Though there seem to be fewer of them about nowadays hereabouts....

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That particular example of "Google Ngrams" does not cover, exclusively, the meaning to which I am referring. The sense, as in *His injured foot plagued him*, I perceive still to be in regular use. But *Jonny keeps plaguing me to buy him sweets* is what I think has gone out of fashion. Your NGram would cover both instances.

Comment: Your question needs attention, then. 'Why has the use of “plague” as a verb declined?' and the first paragraph are far less specific.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That is why I took care to include the full wording of OED sense 2a (for people who do not have access to the OED). The other one is sense 1 of the verb.

Comment: Maybe you grew up?

Comment: @HotLicks In adulthood I never recall ever having used it with reference to my children or grand-children - and let me assure you they have been and are every bit as capable of 'plaguing' as I was.

Comment: I read stuff like "the project was plagued with problems" fairly regularly.  But you're referring to the use of "... plaguing me to ...", which I don't ever recall hearing/reading (at least not with sufficient frequency to make me notice it).  Maybe it was a local idiom?  I would fully expect "... pestering me to ..." to be used in that case, both now and in the past. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=plaguing+me+to%2C+pestering+me+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplaguing%20me%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpestering%20me%20to%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with OP that informal figurative ***plague** (pester, badger) **someone** [to do something]* sounds somewhat "dated", if not exactly Victorian. And I'm further inclined to see [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=plaguing+me+to&year_start=1860&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplaguing%20me%20to%3B%2Cc0) as supporting evidence for the fact of there being a significant decline over the past century and a half.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well done! You not only have grasped what I was on about, which seemed to miss other people, but you have produced some apparent evidence that my perceptions were accurate. There is no doubt that Norfolk was behind the times in the 1940s/50s. My own grandparents might have been mistaken for characters from Thomas Hardy; hence the Victorian idioms. Do please post this as an answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers [Statistics are a wonderful thing](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=plaguing+me+to%2Cplaguing+me+for&year_start=1860&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplaguing%20me%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplaguing%20me%20for%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Following up on the ngram FumbleFingers cited, the heyday of the usage seems to have been around 1750-1775 (and the plaguing me *for* form seems to take over in the late 18th century and to have fallen off rapidly). https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=plaguing+me+to%2Cplaguing+me+for&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplaguing%20me%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplaguing%20me%20for%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @FumbleFingers My grandmother, whom I knew intimately as a child, had been born in 1882. Between circa 1900 and 1910 she had worked in domestic service in London with a relatively well-to-do family. I recall how she would refer to those Edwardian times as *the good old days* - I suppose they were 'good' when compared to the period 1914 to 1945 - two world wars and a depression in between. She used the expressions *plagued me to* and *plagued me for* quite liberally.

Comment: @TimRomano I have added to my OP the OED citations, which start in 1595.

Comment: @WS2 - I'll point out that I presented the same Ngram as the one you so highly praised FumbleFingers for, only mine included the alternative "pestering" to show that there was likely a replacement of "plaguing" with "pestering" ca 1920.

Comment: @HotLicks I praised Fumble Fingers primarily for grasping the question, which others had failed to do, and for providing some level of evidence.to confirm my perceptions about OED sense 2a having declined. However nothing I said should infer anything other than that I remain a sceptic of the accuracy of Google Ngrams.

Comment: My apologies, @Hot Licks. I just saw **books.google** and assumed it was "Google Books" (didn't notice the **ngrams** bit). So I put *my* link in because I thought that was the only way to present evidence of a ***trend***. But as I now see, yours had/has even better search terms than mine for suggesting a decline in the specific usage we're looking at here. I quite agree ***pester*** (cf *pestilence = plague*) is much more common for such contexts today.

Comment: @HotLicks After a careful review of what you wrote I can see that I did not pick up on the *ngrams* bit, possibly for the same reason as Fumble Fingers. But I can now see that you did have a thorough grasp of what it was I was asking. My apologies.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The important point I should stress here is that I was referring to people speaking the Norfolk dialect in the 1940s/50s - not BBC English! Your linking of *pestilence* with *plague* is particularly interesting.

Comment: @WS2: I'm sure there's still lots of genuinely "regional" dialect in Norfolk, but I have the feeling usages that were previously more widespread may tend to survive there after falling into disuse in other regions. Which may be partly accounted for by the relatively low population density thereabouts (and physical and/or social mobility are lowers for Norfolkians than the national average, I don't know).

Comment: If we go by [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=always+pestering+me%2Calways+plaguing+me&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Calways%20pestering%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Calways%20plaguing%20me%3B%2Cc0), it looks like the "national average" switched to ***pestered*** (where we previously complained about being ***plagued***) soon after WW1 (written sources prolly lag a bit behind spoken usage). A lot of idiomatic usage shifts seem to occur after the social mix of war. In this case Norfolk may simply be somewhat "behind the times" :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers We spend a lot of time in Norfolk, for family reasons. But generally it is not a place to which people go, to get to anywhere else. Your point about idioms changing following the social mix of war is a good one. During the course of my recent history degree I did some work on 20th-century Italy. It was really only the effects of the first world war that finally made Italy into a unified country. Had it not been for that, then Mussolini, and finally, and perhaps most important of all - football- Italy would still, in the words of Metternich, be "a mere geographical expression".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=plaguing+me+to%2C+pestering+me+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplaguing%20me%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpestering%20me%20to%3B%2Cc0)

"Plaguing me to" was intermittently popular until about 1910, when "pestering me to" rather suddenly gained great popularity.

One suspects that some books published in the early 1900s led to this shift.  A little late for Mark Twain's work, but certainly there were other popular authors who might have used the phrase.  (It occurs to me that the source might have been some sort of periodical or series of dime novels.)

It should also be noted that "plague" has come to be tightly associated with bubonic plague, causing the word to imply something much worse than simple "trouble".  This awareness/association likely occurred in the mid 1800s as a wave of bubonic plague swept through India and Asia.  As a result it would have seemed a misuse of the word to apply it to a child's activities.

Comment: write [ Ngram ] ( add hyperlink ) without spaces and you should see this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=plaguing+me+to%2C+pestering+me+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplaguing%20me%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpestering%20me%20to%3B%2Cc0) instead of an ugly long link.

Answer (score 2):

Until some point about 100 years ago, *pest* and *plague* were near-synonyms. Then, they started to diverge and *pest* became "insect" (that is, a specific, individualized agent that can cause various troubles) and *plague* became "disease" (a broad, vague influence causing negative consequences, including death).

To call a child a "pest" is no compliment, but can be borderline affectionate: she resembles a grasshopper, a ladybug.

To call anyone a "plague" is a (literally) deadly insult: he is comparable to cancer.

A person who continually bothers you is *pestering* you.

A problem that continually harms you is *plaguing* you.

Comment: You do not cite any evidence for what you have said in your first paragraph. Where did you discover this?

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, "he keeps bothering me" would be the replacement

[image]
[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bother%2C+bothering&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbother%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbothering%3B%2Cc0)

As to why, I have no idea.

Comment: But it doesn't summon anything like the same level of disapprobation.

Comment: @WS2 Nowadays, the main emotional response summoned by "he keeps plaguing me" is probably wry amusement.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sounds as if it may be some time since you spent much time with a six-year-old! Lovable as they are, it can, at moments, seem like the plague! I still can't think of a suitable alternative to *she keeps plaguing me for...*

Answer (score -1):

If you look at Google N-gram viewer you will find that the word is used pretty much as frequently as in the past two centuries. Whether as a noun or verb is not clear.

Comment: It's possible to clarify.

Comment: [***plague*** (verb) **vs** ***plague*** (noun)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=plague_VERB%2C+plague_NOUN&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplague_VERB%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplague_NOUN%3B%2Cc0) Make of it what you will.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?  I am fairly new to this site, and some of the downvotes I have seen seem to me to be, well, grumpy.  I upvoted it partly in gratitude for having this lovely usage recalled to my attention.

Comment: From [my comment to the question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/260638/why-has-the-use-of-plague-in-oed-sense-2a-as-a-verb-declined#comment572087_260638), although I accept that sometimes you can make graphs prove anything, I think there's clear evidence to support my gut feel that the *specific* usage OP queries has declined significantly over a considerable period. Besides which, if you've found different when *you* looked at Google N-gram viewer, you should include a link to the relevant evidence (which I suspect will be flawed in some way).

Comment: I feel that a reference to google Ngram is sufficient information for Fumblefingers to make their own investigation. Edwin Ashworth asserts that noun and verb may be distinguished. However, the only distinction I can make in the google Ngram is between plague and Plague. Assuming the first to be more likely to be a verb, its use has declined to about a half of that a hundred years ago, as the original questioner surmised. I do not claim that this information is a whole answer; it is merely part of one.

Comment: @ab2 I'm only guessing, but perhaps the downvoter doesn't appreciate the stance taken  ('I feel that a reference to google Ngram is sufficient information') when tchrist, for instance, has previously expressed site policy: 'We are looking for more substantial answers with documented references, not merely [statements that may possibly be no more than] personal opinion. Those are just comments, not answers.'

Comment: @ab2 Welcome to the site. Yes, there are a few grumpy contributors around. I seldom ever downvote anything, unless I take serious exception to what someone has said e.g. an abusive remark etc. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I'll feel a bit chagrined/hard done by if I'm to be described as "grumpy" because of the "anonymous downvote" I cast here yesterday. At that time, the only NGram I'd seen from any links on this page wasn't sufficiently "context-specific" to make it obvious that the *specific* sense being queried has indeed declined significantly. This specific answer doesn't actually include *any* supporting evidence, but it seems to me it's based on misinterpretation of search terms that are too "generic" to tell us much.